# Getting Webview2 keypress using QAxWidget

Tags: c++, qt, activex, webview2

I'm trying handle key press event from a Win32 [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/win32) inside a Qt widget since the WebView2 control is based on the Component Object Model (COM). I'm trying to use `ICoreWebView2Controller` as `IUnknown` to wrap this inside a `QAxObject` or `QAxWidget` to get access to the COM object and fetch the webview event from my main window event handler.

Do you have any idea on how to handle this ?

Comment: There's an inherent problem with keyboard and WebView2, but you might be able to get away with a low-level keyboard hook: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/468#issuecomment-855810839

Comment: @jRene, I'd like to see how you got COM access to WebView2 in the first place.  I haven't been able to get past that part.  Thanks, R